# Java: Apache Velocity Parser Error on Curly Brace

Tags: java, jquery, velocity

I am working with Apache Velocity, and one of my templates is triggering a parser error.  The lines that cause the exception are:

```
 $slider.animate({height: configMap.extendedHeight})
        .attr('title', configMap.extendedTitle);
```

And the error is

```
Oct 28, 2013 11:34:50 AM org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute log
SEVERE: ResourceManager.getResource() parse exception
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered ")\n                           .attr(\'title\', congifMap.extendedTitle);\n                    return true;\n                } else if(sliderHeight === configMap.extendedHeight) {\n                    " at vml/Slider.vml[line 45, column 71]
Was expecting one of:
"," ...
")" ...
<WHITESPACE> ...

at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:151)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:437)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
...
```

I am new to VTL syntax, and don't see what the error could be caused by in the VTL reference manual

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html

Does anyone know what the cause of this is and how to fix it?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently as of Velocity 1.7 you can exclude block from rendering with the `#[[ ]]#` directive.  in this case one solution is

```
#[[
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Slider = (function () {
        var configMap = {
            extendedHeight: 434,
            extendedTitle: 'Click to retract',
            retractedHeight: 16,
            retractedTitle: 'Click to expand',
            templateHtml: '<div class="slider"></div>'
        }, $slider, toggleSlider, onClickSlider, initModule;
        toggleSlider = function () {
            var sliderHeight = $slider.height();
            if(sliderHeight === configMap.retractedHeight) {
                $slider.animate({height: configMap.extendedHeight})
                       .attr('title', configMap.extendedTitle);
                return true;
            } else if(sliderHeight === configMap.extendedHeight) {
                $slider.animate({height: configMap.retractedHeight})
                       .attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        onClickSlider = function (event) {
            toggleSlider();
            return false;
        };
        initModule = function ($container) {
            $container.html(configMap.templateHtml);
            $slider = $container.find('.slider');
            $slider.attr('title', configMap.retractedTitle)
                   .click(onClickSlider);
            return true;
        };
        return {initModule: initModule};
    })(jQuery);
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function () {
            Slider.initModule(jQuery('#slider'));
        }
    );
</script>
]]#
```

However this still does not answer the first part of the question which is what the first error was actually about.

Answer (score 0):

If $slider is a javascript variable, it will get into conflict with Velocity variables which also start with $: that may explain the parsing error exception.

To say it in another way: Velocity parses this template trying to get the $slider value from the engine.

Comment: The context is empty, so `$slider` should literally render as `$slider`.

Comment: See here:  http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences

Comment: When velocity see $slider.animate(...), it tries to call the method animate() of the variable slider stored in the context. If this variable does not exist, you will get this exception. Check here for more info: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#variables

Comment: Ok, great, that makes sense, so I wonder how to escape it properly?  Ill try the \ next

Comment: So slider is not defined in the context, and so it is ignored, other ideas?

Comment: My piece of advice would be to use the jQuery variable (instead of $) for jQuery and keep the $ for velocity variables. Here is a list of different options: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.fr/2010/10/dont-confuse-jquery-and-velocity.html